# PHP - Instantiated class function calling twice

Tags: php, class, fwrite, instances

I'm trying to guess why an undesired action is performing in my code. This is my code:

***index.php***

```
include_once("MyClass.php");
new MyClass();
```

***MyClass.php***

```
class MyClass{

     private $LOG;

     function __construct(){

        require_once("Initializer.php");
        $initializer = new Initializer();
        $this->LOG = $initializer->log;

        //Calling the function that performs twice
        $this->LOG->log("test");

     }

}
```

***Initializer.php***

```
class Initializer{

     public $log;

     function __construct(){

          require_once("Log.php");
          $this->log = new Log();

     }

}
```

***Log.php***

```
class Log{

     function __construct(){
           echo "This is not displaying twice";
     }

     //This function is performing twice
     public function log($msg){
        $logFile = fopen(TARGET_FILE, "a+");
        fwrite($logFile, $msg . "\n");
        fclose($logFile);
     } 

}
```

I'm getting as an output in `TARGET_FILE`:

```
test
test
```

Everytime I execute `index.php`.

Where's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go check in browser dev tools, network panel, how many requests actually get made to your index.php file, when you load the page "once" ...

Comment: `a+` means it appends the text to the file, could it just be that you executed the code twice ?

Comment: @teeyo Code is not called twice at least in written code. It's exactly the same as detailed above. Thanks.

Comment: @CBroe Dev tools shows indeed two calls, but the second one is quickly removed from the list. How is this possible? :S

Comment: Some sort of redirect? Use the "preserve log" option (might be called differently in different browsers.)

Comment: @CBroe when "preserve log" is enabled, only 2 requests are listed: domain name and favicon.ico. I just noticed that when dev tools is opened (cache disabled) the function gets executed 4 times...

Comment: Most probably your `TARGET_FILE` already existed and you simply appended to it. Either way try writing also the current timestamp to see when those messages are being written: `fwrite($logFile, time() . " " . $msg . "\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with PHP. I checked my `.htaccess` file which had this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php [L]
```

I removed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and it works as expected.